# Regex to capture BBAN from IBAN?

Tags: c#, regex, banking

I found a regular expression that matches all IBAN numbers from all countries [here](http://snipplr.com/view/15322/iban-regex-all-ibans/):

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{7}([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,16}
```

I tried to adjust it so that is has two capturing groups, one for the country code (the first two letters), and one for the account number (last 10 digits?)

```
"^(?<CountryCode>[a-zA-Z]{2})[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(?<AccountNumber>[0-9]{7}([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,16})"
```

The regex above does not work to capture the account number. I want to capture the last 10 digits basically, but since BBAN is different in all countries (that is why IBAN is invented) this is not always similar.

I hope someone can provide me with some ideas.

/Edit I changed it to:

```
"^(?<CountryCode>[a-zA-Z]{2})[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}([0]*)(?<AccountNumber>([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,16})";
```

and this works in my unit test on a Dutch number, I am not sure about other countries though. I would still love to hear your remarks.

Comment: The last group in that regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,16}` captures 0 to 16 characters. Is that what you want in the named group `AccountNumber`?

Comment: Well capture everything after the 0 was basically the idea. But I decided to only capture Dutch BBAN for now, since that is our country.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the BBAN is everything except the country code and the check digit. In NL it so happens to be 4 letters and the rest is the bank account, but it can be of any format. So basically, the "official" BBAN is everything ignoring the first 4 alphanumerics.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Structure